# Real Analysis Sequences past exam question

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

Let $0<a<b$ be two fixed real numbers and $(a_n)$ be recursively defined by: $$a_{n+1} = \frac{a_n^2+ab}{a+b}$$ where $a_1 = c>0$.

(i) Suppose that $a<c<b$. By induction show that $a\leq a_n \leq b \  \forall n $. Prove that $(a_n)$ is decreasing and find $\lim a_n$.
(ii) Show that if $c>b$, then $(a_n)$ does not converge.

I managed to do the first part and found that the limit is $a$ as the roots of the equation when taking limits on both sides are $a \text{ and } b$ ,but $(a_n)$ is decreasing and $a<b \to \lim a_n = a$. I could not prove that for $c>b$ the sequence diverges.

I tried proving that $(a_n)\geq c > b \ \forall n $ using induction and that $(a_n)$ is increasing so that the roots of the limit would be out of range of $(a_n)$ but got stuck and I am not sure if it's the right way to proceed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $a_n>b$ then $a_{n+1}>a_n.$ So if $a_1=c>b$ then the sequence $(a_n)_n$ is strictly  increasing; if it did not go to $\infty$ then $a_n$ and $a_{n+1}=(a_n^2+b)/(a+b)$ would both converge to a limit $L>a_1$

implying $L=(L^2+ab)/(a+b) $

implying $(L-a)(L-b)=0$ with $L>a_1=c>b>a,$ which is absurd.

Comment: In general, in a recursive sequence $a_{n+1}=f(a_n),$ if $f$ is a continuous function and if $a_n$ converges to $L$ then $L=f(L).$

Answer (score 0):

If $a_1 =c >b$ we can pick $t$ such that $a_1 >t >b$. Let us show that $a_n >t$ for all $n$. This is true for $n=1$. If $a_n >t$ then $a_{n+1} >\frac {t^{2}+ab} {a+b} >t$ because $(t-a)(t-b) >0$. By induction $a_n >t$ for all $n$. If possible let $a_n$ converge to some number $s$. Then $s=\frac {s^{2}+ab} {a+b}$ and this can be written as $(s-a)(s-b)=0$. But this is a contradiction because $a_n >t >b$ for all $n$ so we must have $s=\lim a_n \geq t >b >a$